# How is DMA physically done when using memory mapped IO

Tags: cpu-architecture, dma

im a quite a beginner when coming to HW but thinking recently that I wanted to build a computer around a 6502 chip. Then started thinking of I/O devices in conjunction with DMA in a memory mapped I/O system. How does this work? E.g. if I have an RS-232 card exposing the three "standard" ports (2xconfig and 1xread/write) how would that work with DMA? Would I set up the DMA so that it point to data I want to send in RAM, number of bytes e.t.c. then the DMA device would access my RS232 hardware sending one byte a time waiting for the device to be ready between each byte? If that is the case it seems very specialized and device dependent how DMA transfers are done. I can't seem to find any good resources describing how this work, if you have links please lemme know

thanks

Comment: If you're too new to it, perhaps, reading the intel 8237 DMA chip documentation may help to get the picture. I don't know what DMAs were normally used with the 6502 and such.

Comment: Btw, there are UART chips with internal buffers for multiple (up to 15-16?) bytes. If you use one of those, you may send and receive multiple bytes at once per interrupt. That is, without polling and without executing the ISR on each and every byte sent or received.

Comment: Ah Thanks, good idea reading through that spec! I guess those uart devices then exposes 16 ports to user? But it’s a neat idea, my plan is to use a max232 connected to a pic , then expose registers as sram or similar, so pretty easy having multiple ports , then you could have a dedicated dma channel configured for these, and very fast in interrupt handler fire that off

Comment: Sorry, typically you use the same port to send to or receive from. I was merely pointing at the fact that you may benefit from a good UART chip without involving DMA.